# my code runs fine on online compiler but gives an EOF error on GEG idle

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, eof, traceback, eoferror

function part does not give the error.its from the main part of the code

```
def convertFive(n):

    l=[]
    rev=[]
    while(n>0):
        l.append(n%10)
        n=n//10

    rev=l[::-1]


    for i in range(len(rev)):
        if(rev[i]==0):
            rev[i]=5


    print(*rev,sep="")

//main
t=int(input())
for i in range(t):

  n=int(input())
  convertFive(n)
```

the end of file error is in the main part.